# DevExpress custom grouping: groups also have columns, groups and independent rows exist simultaneously

Tags: asp.net, .net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I need to display message groups and messages inside a DevExpress grid.

Requirements:

- message groups and messages have the same columns
- groups have a special column with a '+'/'-' sign which specifies if the group is closed or open
- when a group is closed its messages do not appear in the grid
- when a group is opened by clicking the '+' sign its messages need to appear in the same grid underneath the group
- the grid can have both groups and simple messages

The grid also needs to allow sorting, filtering and paging.

Is there a simple way to achieve this using DevExpress features?

NOTE: I've seen the DevExpress grouping demo, but this is different from my requirements because:

- in the demo only the grouping value is displayed whereas in my grid I need to see all the columns of the message group
- all rows are grouped (groups and messages can not exist at the same time)

EDIT: I have eventually abandoned this idea as it seemed to much trouble. What I did instead was add a column with a clickable link for groups; when the user clicks the link a popup appears with the children; it was much easier and more intuitive for the user

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress has a tree.

Each Group can be a root level node and each message a node within its group, or a message could be another root level node (IE not within a group).

All nodes share the same columns. Each group that has messages will have a '+/-'